# Could a planet with three-quarter earth gravity and neon-/argon-based atmosphere exist, and what would life do with it?

Tags: internal-consistency, atmosphere, xenobiology, currents

I'm creating a world with three-quarters the gravity of Earth, and the composition of the atmosphere is as followed:

- 74% Neon (or Argon)
- 18% Nitrogen
- 5% Oxygen
- 1.6% Carbon Dioxide
- 0.9% Water Vapor
- 0.5% Trace

The questions I have in mind are:

- Would Neon or Argon work better for this planet?
- Could the atmosphere exist with the low gravity?
- Could life as we know survive on this world, and could organisms evolve in a way to biologically contain neon/argon to use as bioluminescence?

Comment: argon is heavy 74% is a catastrophic level of  greenhouse gas... your planet would be  a desert ball of fire, on earth 0,04% of greenhouse gases on the atmosphere are just enough to put the world at great risk, and our greenhouse gases are way lighter than argon.

Comment: @渡し守シャロン Argon isn't a greenhouse gas; heat goes through the certain wavelengths that trap heat. Are you saying because the atmosphere would be so dense that it would reek havoc on the planet's surface?

Comment: I'm not sure this can work, for reasons mentioned in the accepted answer to [your other question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51688/could-an-atmosphere-of-neon-oxygen-and-carbon-dioxide-support-life-and-what-ki). Life on Earth relies on the nitrogen cycle, which is itself based on Earth's atmosphere being three-quarters nitrogen and how that nitrogen reacts chemically with life. If you replace most of that nitrogen with one of the noble gases like argon or neon (known for their _lack_ of reactivity), I'm not sure you can have any life, at least not anything we'd recognize.

Comment: @Palarran the life on the planet might evolve to use the nitrogen more efficiently. In any case, "atmospheric life" is relatively new, most of the time the life evolved in water, so it is the concentration of nitrogen in water which matters.

Comment: @Palarran How much of the atmosphere should be nitrogen in order to sustain life; would it have to be the main component of the atmosphere?

Comment: @Twig I'm not sure anybody can give you an exact figure, and I'm not an expert on this. All I can do is point out that Earth (the only planet known to support life) has an atmosphere of 75-80% nitrogen, and that plant life depends on that nitrogen to thrive; agricultural fertilizer is mostly nitrogen, with some other materials. Your proposed atmosphere is replacing most of that nitrogen (a fairly reactive gas) with neon or argon (both notable for their lack of reactivity). Maybe a much denser atmosphere could help, by providing sufficient nitrogen despite the lower concentration?

Comment: @Palarran In that case, an argon atmosphere could work as it's denser then nitrogen at 1.78 grams per liter (compared to 1.25 grams per liter). Perhaps nitrogen could be abundant in the soil but never go to the atmosphere, just stored by plant/bacteria-like organisms; those organisms could get consumed by higher organisms, witch release it back into the soil for more nitrogen-storing organisms or plants to use.

Comment: Greenhouse gas effects can probably be ignored, as far as story-telling goes; you can just move the planet's orbit closer-to or further-from the star to compensate.

Comment: As for water vapor, you probably can't pick it like that.  The maximum amount of water vapor the atmosphere can hold is determined by thermodynamics; once you hit that limit, it starts to precipitate (rain, etc.).  This limit varies heavily with temperature; water's far more volatile when it's warm.

Comment: What's the total pressure? Percentages don't mean much unless you know what they're percentages *of*.

Comment: Since this question popped up in the suggested edits list, I've taken the time to review it. Unfortunately it doesn't match the community's current guidelines mainly because there are a good 3 questions (lacking focus). Moreover, the first question is a bit unclear : what does "work better" mean in this context? Would it "work better" if life is more thriving, if the atmosphere was more dense, if it had nicer colors in the sky...? We could also use some data from the sun to reliably answer whether the atmosphere would be there or not.

Answer (score 4):

If it has a powerful magnetic field, 3/4th G should be more than enough to hold onto an atmosphere. A magnetic field has a lot more to do with keeping an atmosphere than raw gravity, because it keeps it from being stripped away by solar wind. Look at mars, for an example - Its magnetic field died long ago, and the sun slowly eroded the atmosphere away, but its gravity is only a third of earths. Titan, on the other hand, has only 1/6th earth gravity, but has a healthy atmosphere because it's protected by Saturns magnetic field. Also, argon, being heavier, would make for a denser atmosphere, so you could achieve earth-like pressures even with the lower gravity (if you want to.)

As for the composition itself, neon and argon are just as inert as our nitrogen, so whatever life there is is probably going to be oxygen-breathing. Oxygen is the most reactive element in the universe, so it only makes sense to use it in your biochemistry. That being said, if they were to visit earth they'd probably suffer oxygen toxicity, since they're used to breathing a very rarefied mixture.

As for the lights, sure, why not? It might actually be easier for them to develop the technology - Gas discharge lamps simply excite Argon/Neon/Xenon/Ect until it starts to glow. We have to contain the gas in a bulb because if we don't it'll diffuse into our nitrogen (and non-Argon/Neon) atmosphere. On the world you're talking about, something as simple as a static spark would have an orange or violet glow. I'd imagine them having some very pretty thunderstorms.

Side benefit: Any kind of Taser or Laser weapon that has a mundane invisible beam on earth would be very vibrant and colorful on their world.

Comment: Titan orbits Saturn not Jupiter lol, and Titan can sometimes face the brunt of the solar wind since it is not always fully protected. The gravity of Mars  isn't 1/2 it is about one third at 0.37 G

Comment: @Stephanie I always derp out and confuse jovian and saturnian moons. It's a personal weakness.

Comment: @Stephanie - maybe this will help you sort out that confusion. I've found it really helpful for visualising all the smaller bodies in the solar system. http://planetary.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/comparisons/20150714_the-not-planets-widescreen-version-2.png

Comment: Oxygen is far from the most reactive element. Fluorine is much worse.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with reality check: if such atmosphere is possible that would require clearly different planet creation. Earth was stripped of its atmosphere at least during Late Heavy Bombardment. (or more timess) All atmosphere was lost, and a new one was formed. That's why we have only trace amount of neon in our athmosphere, even though it's abundant in the universe. We have argon, only because it used to be radioactive potassium which underwent beta decay.

(My only idea is forming this planet in some slow accretion way far away from its parent star, and let it later migrate. But it would create a melted ice world, which would have only sea surface)

If you have such quantities of argon (which is more plausible) than your planet used to be really radioactive...